# Windows Command Line Scripting - Prompt for value

Tags: windows-10, command-line, script, parameters

I have a windows script that simply moves and renames files from one directory in to a series of subdirectories.  I would like to have the script prompt the user for the date of the files. Currently I have it where it is passed via the command line. But if a user does not provide the value it still runs.

Here is the current script that I am using

```
cls
set myParam=%~1
echo %myParam%

move .\OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_ENGL_ENRL*.CSV OTEAS-Stdnts_w_CUNY_ENGL_Enrl\OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_ENGL_ENRL_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_MATH_ENR*.csv .\OTEAS-Stdnts_w_CUNY_MATH_Enrl\OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_MATH_ENR_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_DEG*.csv .\OTEAS-Ext_Degree_and_ENG_flag\OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_DEG_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_ENG_COL*.csv .\OTEAS-Ext_Education_Eng_Col_Lv\OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_ENG_COL_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_MTH_HS*.csv .\OTEAS-Extern_Education_Math_HS\OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_MTH_HS_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_SRVC_IND_ACT*.csv .\OTEAS-Active_Service_Ind\OTE_OTEAS23_SRVC_IND_ACT_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_CUNY_DEGR*.csv .\OTEAS-CUNY_Awarded_Degrees\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_CUNY_DEGR_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_GRP_HIST*.csv .\OTEAS-Student_Group_Recs\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_GRP_HIST_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_LIST*.csv .\OTEAS-Admit_RDEF_Student_List\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_LIST_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_TEST_REC*.csv .\OTEAS-CF_Student_Test_Recs\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_TEST_REC_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_TRNS_CREDS*.csv .\OTEAS-Transfer_Credit_ENG_MTH\OTE_OTEAS23_TRNS_CREDS_%myParam%.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set /p` to *Prompt for user input*.

Something like this:

```
set /p myParam=Enter a value:
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you require the user to give the date as parameter to the script.

Given that you want to force this, it is better to prompt the user to enter something at runtime.

This can be done by the use of set /p.

Next, by using an IF statement, you can validate if at least something was entered, and use that. For proper validation, I would recommend powershell though, then you can check if the entered value is actually a date.

With this in mind, your script would become something like this:

```
cls
set /p myParam=Please enter a date:
echo The date entered was: %myParam%.

if "%myParam%"=="" then goto exit

move .\OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_ENGL_ENRL*.CSV OTEAS-Stdnts_w_CUNY_ENGL_Enrl\OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_ENGL_ENRL_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_MATH_ENR*.csv .\OTEAS-Stdnts_w_CUNY_MATH_Enrl\OTE_OTEAS23_CUNY_MATH_ENR_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_DEG*.csv .\OTEAS-Ext_Degree_and_ENG_flag\OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_DEG_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_ENG_COL*.csv .\OTEAS-Ext_Education_Eng_Col_Lv\OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_ENG_COL_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_MTH_HS*.csv .\OTEAS-Extern_Education_Math_HS\OTE_OTEAS23_EXT_ED_MTH_HS_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_SRVC_IND_ACT*.csv .\OTEAS-Active_Service_Ind\OTE_OTEAS23_SRVC_IND_ACT_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_CUNY_DEGR*.csv .\OTEAS-CUNY_Awarded_Degrees\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_CUNY_DEGR_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_GRP_HIST*.csv .\OTEAS-Student_Group_Recs\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_GRP_HIST_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_LIST*.csv .\OTEAS-Admit_RDEF_Student_List\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_LIST_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_TEST_REC*.csv .\OTEAS-CF_Student_Test_Recs\OTE_OTEAS23_STDNT_TEST_REC_%myParam%.csv
move OTE_OTEAS23_TRNS_CREDS*.csv .\OTEAS-Transfer_Credit_ENG_MTH\OTE_OTEAS23_TRNS_CREDS_%myParam%.csv


:exit
```

Comment: That’s great. Thank you. 

Wondering is there a way to force the response into a particular format? Ie ####-##-##

Comment: Not with commandline, but with Powershell you could. Well technically, you could use a series of choice commands, but that is very finicky.